# office.context.document is undefined in angular file

Tags: office-js

I have problem in not getting office.context.document in angular file.What i am doing is on click of ribbon button i am redirect to a html page  whose functionality is written in angular js.The html page contain a input box and a button.Onclick of button i am calling a function which is have office.context.document.getfileasync  but it error is coming office.context.document.getfileasync undefined.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var count = 0;
  var INSERTION_TYPE_PLAIN_TEXT = "PLAIN_TEXT";
  var INSERTION_TYPE_RICH_TEXT = "RICH_TEXT";
  var INSERTION_TYPE_LIVE_WIT = "WIT_CONTENT";
  var VAR_META_SEPERATOR = "::";



  angular.module('wpoffice')
    .directive('wittyWordCommandExec', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'witty-save-document-from-ribbon-pop-up.html',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'WordCommandController',
        controllerAs: 'WordCommandCtrl'
      };
    })
    .controller('WordCommandController', WordCommandController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function WordCommandController($scope, $q, ngNotify, $uibModal, witService, $timeout,$http,appData,attachmentService,officeWordService,userProfileService) {
    console.log('WordVariableController init');
    var vm = this;
    vm.init = init;
    vm.createWit = createWit;
    $scope.WitName = "";

 
    console.log(Office.context.document);
    console.log($scope.WitName);

    var fileurl = displayDocumentUrl();
    console.log(fileurl+"hi");

    if(fileurl){
      var filename = fileurl.substr(fileurl.lastIndexOf('/')+1,fileurl.length);
    }
    
    function createWit()
    {

        

       console.log(Office.context);
      console.log($scope.WitName);
      console.log("test function executed");
      console.log(appData);
       userProfileService.getUserProfileData().then(function(response){
          console.log(response.defaultFolderId);
          //console.log(filename);
          saveDocument(appData, witService,attachmentService,response.defaultFolderId,$q,filename).then(function(){
              console.log("Document saved to witty parrot");
          });
      },function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });
    }

    function init()
    {
      console.log("test init fucntion");
    }


    // Get all of the content from a PowerPoint or Word document in 100-KB chunks of text.
    function saveDocument(appData, witService,attachmentService,defaultFolderId,$q,filename,witname) 
    {

      
       var deferred = $q.defer();
     
      appData.isContentLoaded = false;
      console.log("inside sendfile");
      console.log(Office.context.document);
      Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed",
          { sliceSize: 100000},
          function (result) {
              console.log(result);
              if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                  var myFile = result.value;
                  var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
                  var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
                  console.log("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);
                  getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived,appData, witService,attachmentService,defaultFolderId,$q,filename,witname).then(function(){
                    console.log('inside getSliceAsync');
                    deferred.resolve();
                  });
              }
              else {
                deferred.resolve();
                  console.log(result.status);
              }
          });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-rem layout-column pad-box-10" ng-controller="WordCommandController as WordCommandCtrl">


    <div class="layout-column flex-rem witty-text-input-container">
       <input autofocus type="text" ng-model="WitName" placeholder="Enter wit name" class="flex flex-rem">
    </div>

        <button ng-click="WordCommandCtrl.createWit()" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary">
          <span class="ms-Button-label">CREATE WIT</span>
        </button>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hook up the [Office.initialize](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.initialize) event to gain access to the Office APIs.

There are a number of Angular samples [here](https://dev.office.com/code-samples#?filters=office%20add-ins,angularjs).

Comment: You can also take a look at [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab), which was also built with Office.js + Angular 4, and which shows our pattern for using Office.initialize.